# How to check if md5 hashing code is hung or running?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am fingerprinting a 5TB drive. The problem, I started the code 3 days ago and still has not finished.

I am using Windows 10 Pro, Windows PowerShell ISE, with 5TB External Drive which is about 95% full with approximately 2 million files.

```
Get-childitem -recurse -file | 
  Select-object @{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName |
  Select-object -expandproperty Hash}},lastwritetime,length,fullname |
  Export-csv "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Is there any way to check if the code is running or crashed (without stopping a possibly running code and wasting 3 days of fingerprint)?

To avoid this next time, maybe a "cheap" and simple status update (display) from the code while it is progressing?

Comment: That should be easy enough. Get something like procmon from sysinternals and find your powershell.exe and monitor its progress. If it is reading more files then just wait longer. _To avoid this next time_ You should look into parallel processing with jobs and or workflows and possibly a logging mechanism as an easier way.

Comment: "procmon from sysinternals" is this in windows 10? or need to get it from somewhere?

Comment: [Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Also could you not just look to see if your CSV has more rows by checking its size? Since it should be getting larger after each file processes

Comment: i checked the csv. 11 million lines and growing. it should be 2 million files max. my gut feeling that there is a filename problem somewhere on the disk that causing a loop, so it keeps rehashing the same sets of files indefinitely. any suggestion to test what is the trouble files (likely weird characters in filename).

Comment: Make a copy of the file and then perhaps pull it into excel and use from filters to see where the variances are. At first glance I cannot guess what the issue is so you will have to investigate yourself. Since you write the fullname you will know if there are any duplicates from that column alone.